# Is it possible to say whether current configuration of Conway's Life will lead to empty field or not?

Tags: conways-game-of-life

So I'm asking the question out of complete and pure curiosity. Is there any way to deterministically calculate that certain configuration will lead to death and, as a result, empty field? Or is the brute-force approach (calculate all the steps) the only efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminds me of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).  I believe this is an example of the halting problem, because an empty field is essentially just the end of the program.

Comment: What the OP may or may not know is that you can build Conway Life patterns that are Turing Machines.